# Retrieve all possible combinations of n items, of a given size k and apply function sum on another column

Tags: r, dplyr, combinations, permutation

I have a df looking like:

```
  item value
1    a     1
2    b     4
3    c     3
4    d     2
5    e     6
6    f     8
7    g    11

df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
        item = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"),
       value = c(1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 11L))
```

I want to generate all possible combination of items of size = 3, like:

```
size <- 3

combo_3 <- combn(df$item, size, simplify = F)
```

Now I want to summarise this result.

I would like a dataframe containing:

- A combination index
- The items in the combination
- The sum of the of the column value for that specific combination

Here the example dataframe for the first combination occurrences:

```
combo_index    item    sum_total
1                 a        8
1                 b        8
1                 c        8
2                 a        7
2                 b        7
2                 d        7
3                 a        11
3                 b        11
3                 e        11 
             ...
             ...
             ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same idea as @akrun, but with `map_dfr` instead of `rbindlist` and `lapply`

```
library(tidyverse)

map_dfr(
  combo_3, 
  ~ data.frame(item = .x, sum_total = sum(df$value[df$item %in% .x])),
  .id = 'combo_index')

#     combo_index item sum_total
# 1             1    a         8
# 2             1    b         8
# 3             1    c         8
# 4             2    a         7
# 5             2    b         7
# 6             2    d         7
# 7             3    a        11
# 8             3    b        11
# 9             3    e        11
# 10            4    a        13
# ...
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved with looping through the `list`, get the corresponding 'value' based on matching with the 'item' from 'df', create a `data.frame`, and `rbind` the `list` elements

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(combo_3, function(x) data.frame(item = x, 
  sum_total = sum(setNames(df$value, df$item)[x])) ), 
            idcol = 'combo_index')
#     combo_index item sum_total
#  1:           1    a         8
#  2:           1    b         8
#  3:           1    c         8
#  4:           2    a         7
#  5:           2    b         7
# ---                           
#101:          34    f        21
#102:          34    g        21
#103:          35    e        25
#104:          35    f        25
#105:          35    g        25
```

---

Or better would be to `stack` the `list` to a two column `data.frame`, `left_join` with the original dataset, grouped by 'ind' get the `sum` of 'value'

```
library(tidyverse)
setNames(combo_3, seq_along(combo_3)) %>% 
    stack %>%
    left_join(df, by = c("values" = "item")) %>%
    group_by(ind) %>%
    mutate(value = sum(value)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(combo_index = ind, item = values, sum_total = value)
# A tibble: 105 x 3
#   combo_index item  sum_total
#   <fct>       <chr>     <int>
# 1 1           a             8
# 2 1           b             8
# 3 1           c             8
# 4 2           a             7
# 5 2           b             7
# 6 2           d             7
# 7 3           a            11
# 8 3           b            11
# 9 3           e            11
#10 4           a            13
# ... with 95 more rows
```

Answer (score 3):

With data.table (plus reshape2 indirectly), you can "melt" the combn and join:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

res = df[melt(combn(item, 3, simplify=FALSE)), on=.(item = value)]
res[, sum_total := sum(value), by=L1][]

     item value L1 sum_total
  1:    a     1  1         8
  2:    b     4  1         8
  3:    c     3  1         8
  4:    a     1  2         7
  5:    b     4  2         7
 ---                        
101:    f     8 34        21
102:    g    11 34        21
103:    e     6 35        25
104:    f     8 35        25
105:    g    11 35        25
```

`melt` assigns name `L1` by default, but this can be set to another value with `setnames`.

This way of storing data, with repeated values in `sum_total`, is not "tidy"; and it would make more sense to use two tables (one indexed by `L1`/combo index, with the total; and another indexed by `L1`+`item`). See [the tidy data paper](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10) if interested.